# How do I create three objects with one line of code?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

How would I create three empty hashes with a single line of code?

I know that `a = b = c = Hash.new` won't work, since that'll create three references to the same Hash object.

`a,b,c = Hash.new` will assign the `Hash` to `a`, but `b` and `c` remain `nil`.

I know I could do `a, b, c = Hash.new, Hash.new, Hash.new`, but that doesn't look very DRY.

Comment: Those three hashes gotta come from *somewhere*.

Comment: @delnan So, there's no shortcut for creating multiple instances of a class? :(

Comment: Since your `Hash.new` calls use neither arguments nor a block, you can shorten it to `a, b, c = {}, {}, {}`.

Comment: There might be an expression for "clone this N times", which would work but wouldn't be any shorter. If you need this frequently enough to be a problem, you're propably doing something wrong (e.g. not using collections enough).

Comment: I need it just once, but I was curious wether it's possible. Guess not. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I posted as a comment, I think `a, b, c = {}, {}, {}` is the best way, because it's short, and easy to read. If you really want to do it in a more complicated way, something like this will work:

```
>> a, b, c = Array.new(3) { Hash.new } #=> [{}, {}, {}]
>> a #=> {}
>> b #=> {}
>> c #=> {}
```

Comment: Well, I was looking for a language construct, but since there's none, and I fancied your answer the most, I'll accept it. All the other answeres were quite good, too, though. (I did try using `3.times.map { Hash.new}` myself, but I wasn't too happy with it). Thanks, everyone :D

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure if I would use that, but it is possible:

```
a, b, c = 3.times.map { Hash.new }
# or
a, b, c = (1..3).map { Hash.new }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you already marked an answer, I'd throw in another way which I find as the simplest one:

```
a,b,c = [{}]*3
```

Comment: Looks like this will set `a`, `b` and `c` to the same hash instance. `>> a,b,c = [{}]*3 #=> [{}, {}, {}] 
>> b[1]=1 #=> 1
>> a #=> {1=>1}
>> c #=> {1=>1}`

Comment: It will set all three to the same hash value. The reason is Ruby allocates the `{}` first, then duplicates it three times. It doesn't duplicate three arrays of `{}` then assign them.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not really sure if I would use that, but it is possible:

```
a, b, c = 3.times.map { Hash.new }
#or
a, b, c = (1..3).map { Hash.new }
```

And yet another answer.. since you can simply use `{}` instead of `Hash.new`
The assignation could be like this:

```
a, b, c = 3.times.map{{}}
```